# extend SocketChannel so that SelectionKey returns custom class

Tags: java, sockets, nio

Is there a way to extend SocketChannel in java so that the selection key will return my (let's say Client) class ? I think that i have to implement a socketFactory or something.

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what purpose? If you need context with your SocketChannel, that's what the attachment is for. Basic answer is 'no'.

Comment: Thanks, SelectionKey's attach method was exactly what i needed.